# Vocabulary creation in Blazegraph

Tags: java, blazegraph

I need to create a custom geospatial datatype to represent a polygon in Blazegraph, but I can't do so as it requires defining a vocabulary for this. Would you kindly write to me the concrete steps about how to create a vocabulary in Blazegraph?

Comment: By following the description provided here https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/GeoSpatial, I tried to create a custom geospatial data type. But I learned that to create a data type, I have to create a vocabulary. The vocabulary creation process is described here: https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/InlineIVs, but I could not proceed with this description.

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete and repeatable example of what you tried as well as the result you got and how that differ from your expected result. For more details see [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to define a vocabulary for creating a custom geospatial data type in Blazegraph with a colleague's help. I cloned the Blazegraph code from here https://github.com/blazegraph/database, created the following class and built (using mvn clean install -DskipTests) both the database and blazegraph-jar projects. Finally, used the renamed the blazegraph-jar...jar file as blazegraph.jar and ran this command: java -server -Xmx4g -Dbigdata.propertyFile=RWStore.properties -jar blazegraph.jar.

```
package com.bigdata.rdf.vocab;

import com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore;
import com.bigdata.rdf.vocab.BaseVocabularyDecl;
import com.bigdata.rdf.vocab.Vocabulary;
import com.bigdata.rdf.vocab.core.BigdataCoreVocabulary_v20160317;
import org.openrdf.model.impl.URIImpl;

/**
* 
* A {@link Vocabulary} covering the land use code (LUCODE) data.
* Use the vocabulary by adding a property to the configuration file (RWStore.properties) per below.
* 
* <code>
* 
 com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.vocabularyClass=
 com.bigdata.rdf.vocab.LucodeKGVocabulary
* </code>
*
* @author <a href="mailto:msff2@cam.ac.uk">Feroz Farazi</a>
* @version $Id$
* 
*/
public class LucodeKGVocabulary extends BigdataCoreVocabulary_v20160317 {

private String[] uris = {"http://polygon-1-7",
        "http://my-lat-lon-starttime-endtime-dt"};

/**
 * De-serialization ctor.
 */
public LucodeKGVocabulary() {
    
    super();
    
}

/**
 * Used by {@link AbstractTripleStore#create()}.
 *
 * @param namespace
 *            The namespace of the KB instance.
 */
public LucodeKGVocabulary(final String namespace) {

    super( namespace );

}

@Override
protected void addValues() {
    
    super.addValues();

    for (String uri: uris) {
        URIImpl impl = new URIImpl(uri);
        BaseVocabularyDecl decl = new BaseVocabularyDecl(impl);
        addDecl(decl);
    }

  }

}
```

I put the following configuration parameters in the RWStore.properties file:

```
# Sets journal parameters.
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=bigdata.jnl
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.initialExtent=209715200
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.maximumExtent=209715200
# Sets the textIndex parameter
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.textIndex=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.axiomsClass=
com.bigdata.rdf.axioms.NoAxioms
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.isolatableIndices=false
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.truthMaintenance=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.justify=false
# Use our private vocabularies
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.vocabularyClass=
com.bigdata.rdf.vocab.LucodeKGVocabulary
# Assigns the namespace or repository name
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.namespace=testgeospatialdb
com.bigdata.namespace.geospatialdata.spo.com.bigdata.btree.BTree.
branchingFactor=1024
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=false
com.bigdata.namespace.geospatialdata.lex.com.bigdata.btree.BTree.
branchingFactor=400
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.geoSpatial=true
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.statementIdentifiers=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.geoSpatialDatatypeConfig.1={ 
"config": { "uri": "http://polygon-1-7", "fields": [ { "valueType": 
"DOUBLE", 
"multiplier": "100000", "serviceMapping": "LATITUDE" }, { "valueType": 
"DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", "serviceMapping": "LONGITUDE" }, { 
"valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": "starttime" }, { "valueType": 
"LONG", 
"serviceMapping": "endtime" }{ "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": 
"100000", 
"serviceMapping": "LATITUDE" }, { "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": 
"100000", "serviceMapping": "LONGITUDE" }, { "valueType": "LONG", 
"serviceMapping": "starttime" }, { "valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": 
"endtime" }{ "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", 
"serviceMapping": 
"LATITUDE" }, { "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", 
"serviceMapping": "LONGITUDE" }, { "valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": 
"starttime" }, { "valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": "endtime" }{ 
"valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", "serviceMapping": 
"LATITUDE" 
}, { "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", "serviceMapping": 
"LONGITUDE" }, { "valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": "starttime" }, { 
"valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": "endtime" }{ "valueType": "DOUBLE", 
"multiplier": "100000", "serviceMapping": "LATITUDE" }, { "valueType": 
"DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", "serviceMapping": "LONGITUDE" }, { 
"valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": "starttime" }, { "valueType": 
"LONG", 
"serviceMapping": "endtime" }{ "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": 
"100000", 
"serviceMapping": "LATITUDE" }, { "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": 
"100000", "serviceMapping": "LONGITUDE" }, { "valueType": "LONG", 
"serviceMapping": "starttime" }, { "valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": 
"endtime" }{ "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", 
"serviceMapping": 
"LATITUDE" }, { "valueType": "DOUBLE", "multiplier": "100000", 
"serviceMapping": "LONGITUDE" }, { "valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": 
"starttime" }, { "valueType": "LONG", "serviceMapping": "endtime" } ] } }
```